# Equation with integer part and fractional value

Tags: integers

Solve for  $x\in
\mathbb{R}
$ the equation
$$
\left\{  \frac{\left[  x\right]  +1}{2014}\right\}  =2014x+\frac{1}{2014},
$$
where $\left\{  x\right\}$ is the fractional part of x and the $[x]$ is the integer part of x.$$$$
I took $x=0$ and the equation is verified, but I don't know how to show that this the only one...

Answer (score 3):

We know that $\left\{x\right\}\in[0,1),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, hence 
$$
0\le 2014x+\frac{1}{2014}<1 \implies0\le 2014^2x+1<2014.
$$ From the last inequality we obtein that $x\ge 0$ and $$
x<\frac{2013}{2014^2}<\frac{2014}{2014^2}<\frac{1}{2014}\implies [x]=0.$$The equation begins $$\left\{\frac{1}{2014}\right\}=2014x+\frac{1}{2014}\implies2014x=0\implies x=0.$$